# Access subform in a split view parent - hide from datasheet section

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a split view form with a subform in it. In the datasheet part of the split view Access displays a plus (+) that allows the user to display the subform for that record.

I want to prevent this behavior. How can I hide the subform from the datasheet section, but not the form section?

Even when all the subform columns are hidden the plus remains, even though it expands to show an empty subform.

Can the datasheet section be handled independent of the form view?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the table (split form's recordsource) properties (see picture below).

This may not be ideal solution since it will affect all forms (with datasheet views) that are based on the underlying table, though.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is a linked table so I can't change that property.

Comment: I changed the record source to a `SELECT *` query on the linked table. The Subdatasheet Name setting only effects the datasheet view of the query. It didn't change the datasheet section of the split form based on the query.

Comment: I am glad you figured out! So, as I understand, the solution is **to change recordsource from Table to a query** (e.g. Select * From MyTable)

Comment: No, I was just saying that in order to try your suggestion I had to change the recordsource to a query. It did not have any effect on the "+" in the split form. My solution was to ditch split form view entirely and use a parent form with two subforms that mimic split form view. It gives me a lot more control.

Answer (score 0):

1. insert new (blank) subform (set visible NO)
2. set it lowest Tab Order among subforms (must be the first)

plus sign disapears